# Textview stops updating its contents after orientation change

Tags: android, textview, android-orientation

As the title says, I'm having trouble when updating the contents on my Textview. It all works well, until I change the orientation.

Here is the onCreate of the Activity that holds the Textview:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.transacao);

    screenTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblStatusTrn);
    screenTextView.setText(screenMessage);

    //...
}
```

And here is the code that update the Textview:

```
private void setScreenMessage(String message) {
    screenMessage = message;
    screenTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblStatusTrn);
    screenTextView.setText(screenMessage);
}
```

Even though I keep getting no errors, the Textview doesn't update after I call setScreenMessage. This all happens after the orientation change. If I don't change the orientation, everything works fine.

I already looked into a number of similar questions here, but none of them seemed to work for me.

**EDIT 1**: I don't know if it is relevant, but the setScreenMessage is called from another thread, through an Handler.
Code for the Handler:

```
public void handleMessage(android.os.Message message) {
   //...
   // This command calls setScreenMessage
   command.execute();
}
```

**EDIT 2**: Apparently, using Broadcast did the trick. But that makes me think if it is possible that I had an valid reference to an Activity, even though it is not this reference that is been shown. If that is the case, I might have a useless reference stealing away my memory. Is it possible? Is there a way to check this?

Comment: set screenOrientation:"portrait" to this activity

Comment: I think the entire activity is recreated when you change orientation.

Comment: Have you tried android:configChanges="orientation"

Comment: Try to add attribute android:configChanges="orientation" in your <activity> tag in androidmanifest.xml.

Comment: Thank you for the sugestion, but android:configChanges="orientation" did not work.
I know the entire activity is recreated, but since I am getting a new reference of the Textview, I thought this wouldn't be a problem. Is there another step to do? Getting a new reference isn't enough?
Thank you again for the sugestions.

Comment: aren't your `transacao` xml layout files different in  layout-land and layout folders?

Comment: I only have different transacao.xml for different sizes, not orientation. Even so, both of them have the lblStatusTrn Textview.