# Android - View's method call inside Handler has no effect after Orientation Change

Tags: java, android, android-orientation

My code has a Custom Thread ("MyThread") that sends Messages to the UI-Thread, through a Handler, one each second. After a Message is sent, "handleMessage()" method should change the RelativeLayout's background according to the value of Message's arg1. And it does so, it keeps alternating between green and yellow.

The problems comes when my device experiences an orientation change. The Activity is recreated, some instances are saved through Fragments (as described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)), but the background color stops alternating.

I don't know why this is happening but I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18188999/textview-stops-updating-its-contents-after-orientation-change), without answers, and after that I think this may be happening because of the Handler object.

Here is the code for MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private MyFragment myFragment;

    private Handler handler;
    private MyThread myThread;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        myFragment = (MyFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag("data");

        if (myFragment == null) {
            myFragment = new MyFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction().add(myFragment, "data").commit();

            handler = new Handler() {
                @Override
                public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                    View layout = findViewById(R.id.layout);
                    //Variable arg1 = Color.GREEN or arg1 = Color.YELLOW
                    if (layout == null) Log.e("", "layout is null");
                    else {
                        if (msg.arg1 == Color.GREEN) Log.e("", "Color.GREEN");
                        else if (msg.arg1 == Color.YELLOW) Log.e("", "Color.YELLOW");
                        layout.setBackgroundColor(msg.arg1);
                    }
                }
            };

            myThread = new MyThread();
            myThread.start();
        }
        else {
            handler = myFragment.handler;
            myThread = myFragment.myThread;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        myFragment.handler = handler;
        myFragment.myThread = myThread;
    }

    ///////////////////////////////
    //THREAD FOR SENDING MESSAGES//
    ///////////////////////////////
    public class MyThread extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Message message1 = handler.obtainMessage();
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    message1.arg1 = Color.GREEN;
                    message1.sendToTarget();

                    Message message2 = handler.obtainMessage();
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    message2.arg1 = Color.YELLOW;
                    message2.sendToTarget();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is that wrong to call a view's method inside a handler's method? If it's not so, why it isn't working properly although the RelativeLayout's reference isn't equals null when I call "setBackgroundColor()"? Or is this happening because of the warning: "This Handler class should be static or leaks might occur (com.example.test.MainActivity.1)"?